# NPM не отвечает на любые запросы

Tags: node.js, npm

При любых действиях с `npm` ничего не происходит, просто терминал думает и ничего не выдает. Если принудительно остановить при `npm -v`, то выдает версию, но как исправить, чтобы все нормально работало, я не знаю как.

Comment: у меня была подобная ситуация, но только с установкой express'a. Установка произошла криво и npm не реагировал именно на команды по экспрессу и его модулей. Нода работает? Если нет - то походу просто сервак упал. Если работает, то придется переустанавливать все с нуля. Сочувствую.

Comment: А ему какой-нибудь файрволл доступ в интернет не блокирует?

Comment: Уже столько раз переустанавливал, но все также.

Comment: Хорошая подсказка про файрволл - проверь "sudo ufw status", если у тебя ubuntu. А вообще не плохо бы дополнить вопрос сведениями об операционной системе, заглядывал ли ты в логи сервера? Что все таки с нодой, она работает? Это вообще локальный сервер, или выделенка? Каким способом устанавливал npm -бинарники?

Comment: @raingo 
Win 8.1, 
Нода работает, 
npm ставил вместе с нодой через .msi.

Answer (score 0):

Итого: нашел решение здесь https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/14259
Нашел в C:\Users%UserName% файл .npmrc и удалил его. Все заработало.

Comment: Стоило сделать копию и проанализировать содержимое.